# Euler density of two-dimensional manifolds

Tags: string-theory, differential-geometry, topology

I am asking this question after reading this post: [What is Euler Density?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6784/what-is-euler-density).

For a two dimensional manifold, the Euler density is given by:

\begin{equation}
E_2=2R_{1212}
\end{equation}

(note that $R_{1212}$ is the only independent component of the Riemann tensor in 2d).

Now, integrating over the 2d manifold, we should get the Euler characteristic

\begin{equation}
\chi=\int d^2x \sqrt {(\textrm{det }g)} E_2,
\end{equation}

where $(\textrm{det }g)$ is determinant of the metric. But $E_2=2R_{1212}=R(g_{11}g_{22}-g_{12}g_{21})=R \textrm{ det }g$, where $R$ is the Ricci scalar of the 2d manifold. This gives

\begin{equation}
\chi=\int d^2x (\textrm{det }g)^{\frac{3}{2}} R,
\end{equation}

which contradicts the first term of equation 3.2.3b of Polchinski's 'String Theory', volume 1. What's the reason for this contradiction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I) It seems the resolution to OP's question lies in the difference between

1. the [Levi-Civita **symbol**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol), which is *not* a tensor and whose values are only $0$ and $\pm 1$; and
2. the [Levi-Civita **tensor**](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PermutationTensor.html), whose definition differs from the Levi-Civita **symbol** by a factor of $\sqrt{|\det(g_{\mu\nu})|}$.

II) The 2D Euler-density is

$$ E_2~=~ \frac{1}{8\pi} \epsilon_{\mu\nu}\epsilon_{\lambda\kappa} R^{\mu\nu\lambda\kappa}~=~ \frac{1}{8\pi} \epsilon^{\mu\nu}\epsilon^{\lambda\kappa} R_{\mu\nu\lambda\kappa}~=~\frac{S}{4\pi}~=~\frac{K}{2\pi},$$

where $S=2K$ is the [scalar curvature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_curvature) and $K$ is the [Gaussian curvature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_curvature).  The [Euler characteristics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_characteristic) is

$$\chi~=~\int d^2x \sqrt {| \det  g_{\mu\nu} |} E_2.$$

Comment: Is there a reference from which I can get this information, and perhaps other related information as well?